# (Fluent) NHibernate: force foreign key to null on delete

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a standard parent - child (1:many) relationalship, configured using Fluent NHibernate:

On the parent side:

```
HasMany(x => x.Items).Inverse().Cascade.All();
```

and on the child side:

```
Map(x => x.ItemCategory).Nullable().Index("idx_item_category").Not.LazyLoad()
```

**(Edit in response to epitka's comment:)**

The record is deleted by calling

```
session.Delete(item_category)
```

This is the only operation done in the transaction.

**(End Edit)**

Currently when I delete an ItemCategory record it cascade the delete to all the items, which appears to be working as expected according to the documentation.

What I want is for Item.ItemCategory to be set to null **automatically** when the ItemCategory record is deleted.

I can only seem to turn off the cascade completely, which leads to a broken database (item's referencing a missing category). So, currently I have to do this manually which is a little more error prone than I'd like.

Is it possible to configure this behaviour?
session.Delete(item_category)

Comment: How are you deleting it? Are you removing it from collection, issuing HQL delete, or something else. Show us the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whil it's not possible to do that out of the box, you can probably implement an `IPreDeleteEventListener` that fires an HQL update to set the Items' ItemCategory to null.